# How to pass null value using ajax to PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

I am new to AJAX and PHP.
i want to Replace the Variable value to null.

**`index.php`**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts.js"> </script>

<input type="submit" value="Set Value" onclick="makeRequest('index.php?testvalue=7',   'get', null); "/> 
<input type="submit" value="Unset Value 1" onclick="makeRequest('index.php?testvalue=null', 'get', null); "/> 


<h1><?php echo "PHP Test Value: " .  $_GET['testvalue']; ?></h1>
```

Im trying to change the value of `$_GET['testvalue']` to `null` whenever I hit the **`Unset Value`** button but what is happening is that it doesn't change the `$_GET['testvalue']` variable to null but instead of it does something like `$_GET['testvalue'] = 'null'`;
It appears to me that it passes `null` as a `string`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only strings can pass from a form request. You could instead pass an empty string and interpret that as `null`.

Comment: You mean I shud do something like makeRequest("index.php?testvalue=''", "get", null) ?

Comment: Almost, `makeRequest("index.php?testvalue=", "get", null);`